# How to find a executable file inside a folder?

Tags: vimscript, filesystem, find

I have the path of a folder in a variable, and for a custom debugging script I am making, i need to find an executable file inside that folder (the executable find is guaranteed to exist, but not to be unique).

The executable file is guaranteed to be inside the folder, not in a subfolder. How can I find the path of an executable file (preferably that when called it always returns the same path, although not necessary) in VimScript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question, i know two ways to find all executable files inside a folder:

**readdir( require patch 8.1.1120)**

```
echo readdir('dir', {v-> executable('dir/' . v) && !isdirectory('dir/' .  v)})
```

[:h readdir()](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#readdir%28%29) return a list of files and subdirectories, you can provide a [:h lambda](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#lambda) expression to filter it.
The return name is not preceded with `dir/`.

**glob**

```
echo filter(glob('dir/*', 0, 1), {i,v-> executable(v) && !isdirectory(v)})
```

This is how we do it before `readdir` exists. Third arg of glob make it return a list instead of string. The return name is preceded with `dir/`.